# How to use multiple replace together or at once, Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have some text which is not clear and have so many tags and ascii as follow,

**val =**

```
"\nRated\xa0\n           I have been to this place for dinner tonight.
        \nWell I didn't found anything extraordinary there but indeed a meal worth 
        the price. The number of barbeque item and other both were good.\n\nFood: 3.5/5\"
```

So for making clear this tag I am using

```
  val.text.replace('\t', '').replace('\n', '').encode('ascii','ignore').
decode("utf-8").replace('Rated','').replace('  ','')
```

and using multiple times replace I got my o/p as -

```
I have been to this place for dinner tonight. Well I didn't found anything extraordinary there but indeed a meal worth the price. The number of barbeque item and other both were good. Food: 3.5/5
```

I want to know that is there any way so I can use replace at once only for similar kind of replacement. like in this case -

```
replace('\t', '').replace('\n', '').replace('  ','')
```

Comment: Perhaps use a `translate` table to change each of the undesirable chars to the empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.translate` to delete `\n\t` and then use your replacement for the runs of spaces:

```
>>> val.translate(None,'\n\t').replace('  ','')
"Rated I have been to this place for dinner tonight.Well I didn't found anything extraordinary there but indeed a meal worth the price. The number of barbeque item and other both were good.Food: 3.5/5"
```

The `replace('  ','')` will be problematic with runs of even spaces (they will just be deleted). You might consider a regex:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\b  *\b)',' ',val.translate(None,'\n\t'))
"Rated I have been to this place for dinner tonight.Well I didn't found anything extraordinary there but indeed a meal worth the price. The number of barbeque item and other both were good.Food: 3.5/5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well even do i am not using `replace`, but i still think this is the best way:

```
import string
val = """\nRated\xa0\n           I have been to this place for dinner tonight.
        \nWell I didn't found anything extraordinary there but indeed a meal worth 
        the price. The number of barbeque item and other both were good.\n\nFood: 3.5/5\"""
        """
print(''.join([i for i in ' '.join(val.split()) if i in string.ascii_letters+' ']))
```

Output:

```
Rated I have been to this place for dinner tonight Well I didnt found anything extraordinary there but indeed a meal worth the price The number of barbeque item and other both were good Food
```